# How to skip blank pages in the report?

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 8.5

How to skip blank pages?

I want to skip blank pages or blank field?

Need Formula Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the check box in the Section Expert that says "Suppress Blank Section" to suppress the entire section

To suppress a field you can right click on the field and click Format Field and press the formula button (x+2) next to the suppress check box on the common tab and then enter your formula to use as the suppression logic. To this simply put in a function that would return a boolean value where a returned value of true would suppress the field and false would show the field. Remember that you don't need to check the suppress check box if you have a formula entered. Hope this helps.